How can I increase the shared VRAM on an MSI motherboard with dedicated NVIDIA GPU?
I do extremely heavy tasks in Unreal Engine, so I want to give my PC the maximum amount of VRAM (something like 60 GB) so that leftover RAM will only be enough for OS start. I also have large and fast NVMe SSD and I can store RAM there.
But, when I go to "Click BIOS" from MSI, the maximum amount of Integrated Graphics Share Memory is 160M. I also have a dummy GPU inside CPU, maybe those settings relate to it?.
I cannot find settings for the NOT integrated GPU, how can I increase its shared VRAM?
The PC specs are:

MSI Z790 EDGE WiFi motherboard
NVIDIA GPU (NOT integrated)
64 GB RAM
Windows 11

Here are photos from the BIOS in case somebody needs them:




A graphics card does not have "dedicated shared memory" at all. Depending on your use case, this would not be helpful anyway, in the same way the page file cannot replace physical RAM.

You cant.
The shared memory is only for the integrated GPU.  It cannot share memory to the discreet graphics card.  Your discreet graphics card has its own dedicated memory.  The integrated GPU isnt designed for gaming.  Its just there so there is something that works without a dedicated GPU.
